# Unable to create tables with ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4, compression

I'm attempting to install Nextcloud on MariaDB 10.4.11-MariaDB-1:10.4.11+maria~bionic in a docker container (mariadb:latest sha256:2f11cf2ec18988aec8346a5cf528d69ac3f0f4fc02af79ba28f4fd47b7778d6f).

First thing the installer does is attempt to create a table with `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` in the DDL, which produces an error 140 "Wrong create options".

If I omit the row_format parameter, the table gets created, but with the DYNAMIC row_format.

What's going on here? Did `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` get deleted at some point, or is the version of MariaDB docker is pulling not compiled with it in?

Short of modifying Nextcloud's SQL DDLs, what can I do here?

```
Edit:
```

Finally in a position to add more info about my system, here goes:

First, my my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_large_prefix=on
innodb_file_per_table=on
innodb_doublewrite=off
innodb_page_size=64k
innodb_file_format=barracuda

innodb_compression_algorithm=lz4
innodb_compression_default=ON
```

This results in a startup that contains lines:

```
2020-01-11 07:10:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.4.11+maria~bionic started.
2020-01-11 07:10:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-01-11 07:10:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.4.11+maria~bionic started.
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.11-MariaDB-1:10.4.11+maria~bionic) starting as process 1 ...
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Warning] The parameter innodb_file_format is deprecated and has no effect. It may be removed in future releases. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-file-format/
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_page_size=65536
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-01-11  7:10:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-01-11  7:11:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-01-11  7:11:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-01-11  7:11:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-01-11  7:11:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-01-11  7:11:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-01-11  7:11:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 202590810; transaction id 682452
2020-01-11  7:11:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-01-11  7:11:06 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-01-11  7:11:07 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-01-11  7:11:08 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2020-01-11  7:11:08 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2020-01-11  7:11:08 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.4.11-MariaDB-1:10.4.11+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2020-01-11  7:11:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200111  7:11:30
```

Since I had to alter the create table DDL to even run, this is an example of one such table that *actually* got created:

```
CREATE TABLE `oc_users` (
  `uid` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `displayname` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `uid_lower` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `user_uid_lower` (`uid_lower`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin `PAGE_COMPRESSED`='ON'
```

Note that only `PAGE_COMPRESSED` was a valid option, the `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` option just fails regardless.

The `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` command: https://pastebin.com/LzjsAvAX

And the `SHOW VARIABLES` command: https://pastebin.com/64zpmh2Z

The system I'm running on has 8 GB of RAM, of which MariaDB is using approx 170 MB.

Comment: I don't see anything in MariaDB's Changelogs.  `COMPRESSED` rarely gives more than a factor of 2 in shrinkage, and that comes at a cost.  What do you hope to gain?

Comment: It's not what *I* hope to gain, it's apparently the default for Nextcloud.

Comment: What are your settings for innodb_file_format, innodb_file_per_table, and innodb_large_prefix ?  (The last one may be deprecated or removed.)  And please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I'll retrieve more info when I visit the site again on Tuesday, but file format was (supposed to be) Barracuda, large prefix was on. I do believe there were deprecation warnings regarding setting the file format.

Comment: While you are there, see if you can get the RAM size, GLOBAL STATUS, and VARIABLES:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: @RickJames Added info.  Personally I think MariaDB just actually deprecated it fully without updating docs.

Comment: That could be.  Oracle changed things relating to large_prefix by deprecating it in MySQL 5.7.7 and removing it in 8.0.0.  MariaDB would have picked up the deprecation in about 10.2.x, but would not have removed it very quickly -- after all there could be Master-Slave setups that need consistency.  Perhaps related:  https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18399

Comment: Please explain your rationale in using `innodb_page_size=64k`.

Comment: We're getting way off topic now, but it's the same reason it's normally set to 16Kb https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-diskio.html . The effective application-level sector size on this dataset is 64KB, so I'm matching it for efficiency. Actually, drilling down into that parameter I've found a tiny footnote about that.

Comment: I have looked at thousands of Q&A; I don't recall anyone using 64K.  I am worried that it may be broken.  Hence, that may be the issue.  Do note that the page_size must be set in my.cnf _before_ installing.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to ensure anything related to ZFS was being taken into account prior to getting started. Sadly, I didn't expect ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED to be used and discarded it from memory; and lo, NextCloud decided it was apparently mandatory for... reasons.

Comment: For people using the docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/webhippie/mariadb as the db (for owncloud) you can set `MARIADB_INNODB_READ_ONLY_COMPRESSED=OFF` to solve this issue.

Answer (score 6):

If someone else stumbles across this thread (like me) looking for a solution to a

```
4047 InnoDB refuses to write tables with ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED or KEY_BLOCK_SIZE
```

or similar error from the mariadb for nextcloud, occurring whenever nextcloud tries to write to the DB: the important clue for me was, that this error might be related to an utf8 encoding issue. See here for the nextcloud documentation:

https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/21/admin_manual/configuration_database/mysql_4byte_support.html

**TL;DR:**

The solution from
https://help.nextcloud.com/t/update-to-next-cloud-21-0-2-has-get-an-error/117028/7 for me was :

```
php occ config:system:set mysql.utf8mb4 --type boolean --value="false"
```

followed by

```
php occ maintenance:repair --include-expensive
```

which will fix all tables so that writing to them becomes possible again.

Comment: That looks like an answer to a completely different question.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/171123)

Comment: Sorry if this info is in the wrong place. Maybe the information about the utf8 encoding is also relevant to the original question.

Comment: Oddly enough, this was however exactly the answer to the question that got me here, so... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a [back-handed comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256427/unable-to-create-tables-with-row-format-compressed?noredirect=1#comment507824_256427), I drilled down into the docs for [innodb_page_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size), which briefly mentions:

> ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED is not supported when innodb_page_size is set to 32KB or 64KB.

Since I've tuned the InnoDB page size to match the storage media (i.e. 64 Kb) this meant that `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` was automatically (and permanently) disabled, and there is no explanation in-system to explain that.

So, long story short, you must crawl every micrometer of the docs if you intend to do anything, and any optimizations you may attempt will immediately bring you into "Not supported go away" territory. Otherwise, vague and meaningless errors will occur.

Oh well.

Comment: It also appears that the COMPRESSED option is deprecated and going away soon-ish. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22367 . Hopefully that is a good enough reason to get an upstream code change submitted...

Answer (score 0):

Since you posted the VARIABLES and GLOBAL STATUS, here is an analysis.  (Not much to say.)

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.4.11-MariaDB-1:10.4.11+maria~bionic
- 8 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 1d 04:38:55
- Are you sure this was a SHOW GLOBAL STATUS ?
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` is considerably bigger than the amount of data you have.  Leave it alone unless you are having memory issues, in which case, lower it.

`myisam_sort_buffer_size` is rather high, especially since you appear not to be using MyISAM.

0.6 queries/second -- very low.  I assume you are not having performance problems?

**Details and other observations:**

`( (key_buffer_size / 0.20 + innodb_buffer_pool_size / 0.70) ) = ((128M / 0.20 + 256M / 0.70)) / 8192M = 12.3%` -- Most of available ram should be made available for caching.
-- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

`( open_files_limit ) = 935` -- ulimit -n
-- To allow more files, change ulimit or /etc/security/limits.conf or in sysctl.conf (kern.maxfiles & kern.maxfilesperproc) or something else (OS dependent)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 2,671 / 4096 = 65.2%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 268435456) is bigger than necessary?

`( Innodb_pages_written / Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests ) = 92,258 / 218188 = 42.3%` -- Write requests that had to hit disk
-- Check innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 268435456)

`( innodb_page_size ) = 65,536` -- (As of 5.6.4) Applies to all tablespaces. Smaller may help in random access with SSDs.
-- (Values other than 16KB are rare; care is needed when using such.)

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 91,619,328 / 256M = 34.1%` -- Percent of buffer pool taken up by data
-- A small percent *may* indicate that the buffer_pool is unnecessarily big.

`( innodb_doublewrite ) = innodb_doublewrite = OFF` -- Extra I/O, but extra safety in crash.
-- OFF is OK for FusionIO, Galera, Slaves, ZFS.

`( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 34,577,920 / (103135 / 3600) / 2 / 48M = 0.012` -- Ratio
-- (see minutes)

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 103,135 / 60 * 48M / 34577920 = 2,502` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 50331648). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( default_tmp_storage_engine ) = default_tmp_storage_engine =`

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( sync_binlog ) = 0` -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( myisam_sort_buffer_size ) = 512M / 8192M = 6.2%` -- Used for ALTER, CREATE INDEX, OPTIMIZE, LOAD DATA; set when you need it. Also for MyISAM's REPAIR TABLE.
-- Decrease myisam_sort_buffer_size (now 536870912) to keep from blowing out RAM.

`( character_set_server ) = character_set_server = latin1`
-- Charset problems may be helped by setting character_set_server (now latin1) to utf8mb4. That is the future default.

( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( (query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache / query_alloc_block_size ) = (64M - 64618032) / 1432 / 16384 = 0.106` -- query_alloc_block_size vs formula
-- Adjust query_alloc_block_size (now 16384)

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 10,886 / 22440 = 48.5%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( back_log ) = 70` -- (Autosized as of 5.6.6; based on max_connections)
-- Raising to min(150, max_connections (now 100)) may help when doing lots of connections.

`( thread_cache_size / Max_used_connections ) = 100 / 1 = 10000.0%`
-- There is no advantage in having the thread cache bigger than your likely number of connections. Wasting space is the disadvantage.

**Abnormally small:**

```
1.2 * Key_blocks_used * 1024 = 0
Acl_database_grants = 1
Acl_users = 4
Aria_pagecache_read_requests = 0.38 /HR
Aria_pagecache_reads = 0.38 /HR
Aria_pagecache_write_requests = 0
Com_insert = 0.52 /HR
Com_show_fields = 0
Com_show_tables = 0
Empty_queries = 93 /HR
Handler_icp_attempts = 1.2 /HR
Handler_icp_match = 1.2 /HR
Handler_read_key = 0.35 /sec
Handler_read_next = 6.9 /HR
Handler_read_next / Handler_read_key = 0.00554
Handler_tmp_update = 0
Handler_tmp_write = 19 /HR
Handler_write = 0.56 /HR
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total = 4,096
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead = 0
Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests = 8.8 /sec
Innodb_data_reads = 49 /HR
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written = 0
Innodb_pages_read = 44 /HR
Innodb_rows_deleted + Innodb_rows_inserted = 0.73 /HR
Innodb_rows_inserted = 0.49 /HR
Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads = 15 /HR
Key_blocks_used = 0
Key_read_requests = 0
Key_reads+Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read+Innodb_pages_written+Innodb_dblwr_writes+Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed = 1.8 /sec
Open_table_definitions = 60
Open_tables = 55
Rows_read = 5.5 /sec
Rows_tmp_read = 19 /HR
Table_locks_immediate = 4 /HR
Table_open_cache_hits = 0.47 /sec
innodb_spin_wait_delay = 4
join_buffer_size * Max_used_connections / _ram = 0.00%
lock_wait_timeout = 86,400
query_cache_limit = 131,072
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed / max(Questions, Queries) = 1.46
Innodb_log_writes / Innodb_log_write_requests = 197.8%
Innodb_num_pages_page_compressed = 2,900
Innodb_num_pages_page_decompressed = 841
Innodb_page_compression_saved = 1.71e+8
group_concat_max_len / _ram = 0.01%
histogram_size = 254
myisam_sort_buffer_size / _ram = 6.2%
optimizer_trace_max_mem_size = 1.05e+6
optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 4
performance_schema_max_stage_classes = 160
performance_schema_max_statement_classes = 202
query_prealloc_size / _ram = 0.00%
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
binlog_annotate_row_events = ON
disconnect_on_expired_password = OFF
histogram_type = DOUBLE_PREC_HB
innodb_compression_algorithm = lz4
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
innodb_use_atomic_writes = ON
log_slow_admin_statements = ON
myisam_stats_method = NULLS_UNEQUAL
old_alter_table = DEFAULT
opt_s__engine_condition_pushdown = off
opt_s__optimize_join_buffer_size = on
optimizer_trace = enabled=off
plugin_maturity = gamma
replicate_annotate_row_events = ON
use_stat_tables = PREFERABLY_FOR_QUERIES
wsrep_debug = NONE
wsrep_load_data_splitting = OFF
```

Comment: Thanks for the analysis, even if it's kinda off-topic for the question. It was indeed the global status command as shown by the first line. All the optimizations will be useful in the future, again thanks. Everything is at defaults except for the alterations noted for the my.cnf; no further customization to the variables etc. was done. Some of them are due to adjusting for ZFS.

Comment: @Tsaukpaetra - According to one source, ZFS should not be used for databases.  (I do not have a reference, nor specifics on why they say that.)  Meanwhile, you database is not very busy, so I wonder why you care about compression?  Note:  That row format shrinks the disk footprint by only about 2:1.  Personally, I have never found it worth using.

Comment: It's not that I _want_ to use compression, its that Nextcloud attempts to force it into the create statements; I'll probably raise an issue with them regardless, but it seems oddly inconsistent for a feature to be ghosted with an apparently incorrect error based on docs.
And, ZFS is fine for databases if you know exactly what you're getting into (which I do).

Comment: @Tsaukpaetra - Share your expertise -- Create a Question about "how can ZFS be used with MySQL", then immediately Answer it yourself.

Comment: Your snark is unwarranted and unwanted. Thanks for the help regardless.

Comment: There have been several questions about filesystems; but there have been very few good answers.  I was hoping you might have some advice.  (And get some more reputation points.)

Comment: This does surprise me, you would think the slowest part of databases would be well documented and FAQ'd, but I suppose not enough people venture off the default path to influence this. For now, I may put up a wiki question/answer post eventually, but seeing how low priority this is I may not get to it until the weekend.